# How to make a striped texture that follows the geometry

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

I am looking to create a basic shader with stripes that follow along the geometry however on fiddling around with the shader nodes i can only to get stripes that stick to the axis. I have attached the model below.

Apologies if this is a stupid question but I am really bad with shaders and everything ive found online shows stiped textures on very basic shapes.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want to follow geometry, you're probably going to need to use UV maps. You can still do procedural shaders, but drive them from the UV

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way. You can use *UV coordinates* with the [*Camera Data*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/camera_data.html?#camera-data-node) input node. Then use the [*vector math>cross product*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/vector/vector_math.html#vector-math-node) to combine the two. Then simply use a [*Wave Texture*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/wave.html#wave-texture-node) for the stripes.

Here is the node setup:
[image]

And an example result:

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity; Why would the texture of an object depend on the  camera parameters ? Shouldn'tt the texture be *stuck* to the object and independent of the camera ?